# Django - custom file uploads based on criteria

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I am currently struggling to find the best way to approach the following problem:

I have user registration implemented using django-registration and I want each user to be able to upload different set of documents. Each user will have an "agency", that require some extra documents, however those documents might be different.

So my User base class will have a one-to-one relation with all those base documents required for each user, however I am not sure how to let each agency define their own set of documents and how to tie it to the User.

Thanks.

Comment: If each agency is having different documents, you don't have to give onetoone field to document inside agency. Just give documents as manytomany field in Agency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds to me like these are not one-to-one relations but one-to-many (specifically: one-User-to-many-Documents).

This would result in the Document containing a ForeignKey to the User.
In case one Document could be linked to many users, this may even be a many to many relationship.

In case, documents could be shared between User and Agency, either the Documents also have an optional ForeignKey to the Agency or - if no User needs to be linked to the document you might want to add a Generic Relationship "owner" to the Document that either links to a User or an Agency. See the [Django documentation on Generic Relations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations) for more detail.

However, Generic Relations are a little restricted, making it hard to use them in .filter() and .exclude() queries. Thus, I would recommend you to link to User and Agency in different attributes, if they do not have to share an attribute "owner" or "author", ...

Does each Agency only refer to one User or does an Agency "group" multiple Users? In these cases, refer to the Agency with a ForeignKey in the User model. This would mean, that you need to either inherit from the Django User Model or create a User Profile that contains your additionally defined variables. I personally prefer the second option here. See [the amazing article on SimpleIsBetterThanComplex](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html) for these and other options on extending the User model, including great code examples.

If a User may also be part of multiple Agencies, you could instead use ManyToMany in the Agency and leave the User model alone. However, I would not recommend using this option if you do not intend to have multiple Agencies per user.

### Update 1:

According to your comment, a User only belongs to one agency but an agency may link to multiple users. In this case, the user model should link to the Agency via ForeignKey. If an Admin User should assign Agencies, this is also easy to administrate, (at least in the Django admin), since the admin user then just has to edit the user itself (or the profile) in order to link the agency to it.

Using a post_save signal, you could check for a User that just has been saved, if the file type (type attribute (CharField with or without specific choices set) at the Document Model and Agency as well) required by the Agency is already linked to the User. If it is not, create and link it. The Document model should also contain the File-Field, so that it is easy to check, if the document has been uploaded already.

### Update 2:

Just to help you with this, here is [another great article from SimpleIsBetterThanComplex about Django signals](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/28/how-to-create-django-signals.html).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed comment. An Agency usually groups multiple Users. So let's say each user should upload: CV and Agency_1 requires English certificate and Agency_2 requires "Conviction Status Certificate". The admin user will assign a agency to the users based on some criteria. Does that sound reasonable and make more sense? The user will be part of just one agency.

Comment: That does make more sense, yes. So the Agencies require the user to upload more files, do I understand that right? - Basically, the Agency creates a new Document that has no uploaded file yet but links already to the user for the user to upload the correct document to? I will update my answer according to this, please just comment when it is not what you meant.

Comment: It's more or less something to start thinking about and get my hands on it. I was thinking more like: Agencies upload document templates with: example file or required file to fill + notes about filling it. So if I follow correctly the post_save will go through the assigned documents from the Agency and will create the links?

Comment: Well, how you build your Document model is completely up to you, they can definitely also contain document templates, ...

But if I understood you correctly and each Agency only needs a specific type of file, they could provide all of this information without anyone adding it manually. The post_save signal is your best bet here.And yes, you followed correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the update once again. Well each agency can define own type of files, depending what they need from each user to apply. So Agency_1 can require just couple, and Agency_2 can require 10 documents with some forms provided that they have to fill up.

Comment: Then a template in each Document might be helpful. If the Documents contain ForeignKeys to the Agencies, the Agency object will already contain a document_set field that you can use to query further and iterate through. You might want to use Model inheritance though, in order to distinguish easier between the template documents and the "real" Documents that are lined to user and Agency